# Could an HMAC be used as a hash?

Tags: hash, hmac

MD5 is considered broken and SHA-1 is closely following, but HMACs built around either are still considered relatively secure. It makes me wonder if MD5 and SHA-1 HMACs can be used as secure hashes.

1. Settle on some constant $C$ that will serve the role of $K$.
2. Define a new hash algorithm as $H_C(x)=HMAC(C, x)$.

Could this work?

Comment: Related question: [Why is HMAC-SHA1 still considered secure?](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/26510/why-is-hmac-sha1-still-considered-secure)

Answer (score 14):

HMAC remains unbroken with MD5 and SHA1 because it has a secret key that the attacker doesn't know. Therefore, the attacker cannot carry out huge computations on itself (as is required for finding collisions). [A parenthetic comment: please do *not* misunderstand me; MD5 is **completely broken** and should not be used anywhere including in HMAC.] In contrast, when you fix the HMAC key and make it public, you can once again find collisions. In fact, the specific collision-finding algorithms that we know for MD5 and SHA1 (via differentials) work for *any* IV. When using a key for HMAC that is known, this just gives a different IV. Thus, there is no problem whatsoever finding a collision (in practice, given known methods; not just theoretically).

The solution to SHA1 being broken is to move to SHA256 (and later to Keccak after some more validation time).

Answer (score 5):

Yes, but doing so wouldn't be any more collision-resistant than just settling on some new [IV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkle%E2%80%93Damg%C3%A5rd_construction).

(HMAC is only supposed to be a [PRF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_function_family). ​ Collision-resistance is [significantly harder to achieve](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/~rafael/papers/nonBB.pdf#page=15).)

Comment: May we say that a "random" collision is still hard to achieve? I mean that for a random but fixed key, finding a collision is still hard (meaning birthday paradox hard)

Comment: Some applications of hash functions do no need collision resistance, so it might be a good idea to mention preimage resistances as well.

Comment: @ddddavidee : ​ Only if it's hard in the first place. ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: Do you, @RickyDemer, mean that finding an hmac-collision for HMAC-MD5 would be as easy as for plain MD5? and HMAC-SHA256 infeasible as for plain SHA256?

Comment: @ddddavidee : ​ Yes and yes, for the reason given in Yehuda's answer, and by [the definition of HMAC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2104.txt). ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: Ok thanks, I didn't yet read the edit. (+1 to both)