# Which SHA-1 attacks apply to TOTP tokens?

Tags: sha-1

**Update:** it's actually `hmac(secret, time)`. I'll leave the post as-is, in case someone is ever looking for the `hash(secret+time)` case (for which I provided some reasoning at least), but for TOTP tokens, this question is a duplicate of [Why is HMAC-SHA1 still considered secure?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/26510/2512).

TOTP tokens are basically `hash(secret+time)`. Since you don't know the secret, you can't use them as prefix to compute the random "near-collision block pair", so an attack like *Shattered* won't work here (even if the time matched this random block pair, which it also won't).

Am I correct in thinking that Shattered does not apply to TOTP?

Are there any other attacks that do?

Of course, the recommendation is always to move away from SHA-1, but the question is whether this is a direct vulnerability that a well-funded attacker could exploit or (as far as is public knowledge) just hardening advice.

Comment: Actually it's HMAC-SHA1(secret,time) ([the standard](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6238) defines it in terms of HOTP [which uses HMAC](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4226)).

Comment: @SEJPM Ah yes, important detail that I forgot, thanks for the correction. I think this question might be closed in favor of https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/26510/2512

Comment: Even HMAC-MD5 is still secure, but don't say that out loud since MD5 needs to be sent to the historical trash can.