# Why does NaCl's crypto_auth have twice the security level of crypto_onetimeauth?

Tags: hmac, libsodium

The `crypto_auth` function produces a 256-bit HMAC, with a 512-bit version also available. But the `crypto_onetimeauth` function (and the Box and SecretBox constructions that use it) only produces a 128-bit authenticator. Is there any particular reason NaCl doesn't include a 128-bit HMAC function?

Comment: HMAC can be safely truncated if you want a short auth tag, but I'd avoid truncating Poly1305.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things to consider.

First is that the security models differ: `crypto_onetimeauth` only has to be secure for one message, while `crypto_auth` needs to be secure for any (practical) number of messages. The reason `crypto_secretbox` gets away with using the Poly1305 authenticator internally is that it generates message-specific authentication keys based on the nonce.

Second is the size of the authenticator. There *is* no very secure 128-bit hash function – using MD5 would be iffy even if it is [not known to be broken in HMAC](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/9336/is-hmac-md5-considered-secure-for-authenticating-encrypted-data). You could still truncate HMAC-SHA256 and get a 128-bit authentication tag, but that would require assuming more than just the security of SHA-256.

Comment: It makes sense that truncating a hash would make more assumptions about it's properties than using it unaltered, but it seems like everyone is comfortable making those assumptions about SHA2. NaCl's HMAC-SHA512-256 is just a simple truncation of HMAC-SHA512.

Comment: @JackO'Connor, yes, truncation is all right, and even approved by NIST. OTOH, the user of NaCL could handle the truncation if they want. (BTW, SHA-512/256 is not *just* truncation, it also has a different IV, but that's not really relevant here.)

Comment: Would you consider it kosher to truncate a `crypto_auth` MAC to 16 bytes?

Comment: @JackO'Connor, NIST [says](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-107-rev1/sp800-107-rev1.pdf) (pdf, section 5.3.3) you can even take it down to 32 *bits*! I'd prefer to keep as much as space constraints allow, but 128 bits should be fine.